# Only add if it's not present

Tags: jquery

I only want to add this if it's not already present

```
$('#main_state').append('<label class="check error" generated="true">This field is required.</label>');
```

So I have a loop and I only want to add it the first time...any ideas?

Comment: What else is in `#main_state`?  Other labels?  Why does the label not have a `for` attribute?

Comment: Why not add it before the loop? What is the context? It seems that it does not need anything from the loop.

Comment: there is a select tag with all the states...Do i need a for attribute and is it needed...whats the benefits of it

Comment: felix that was a bright idea .....sometimes u need another point of view to point you to the obvious

Comment: Why don't you add id to label you are appending and check if it exist with selector

Comment: @Tamer: I posted it as an answer ;) :D

Comment: Labels are "for" form data elements, it is an ID reference.  They are not compulsory, but validators do complain if they're not there. eg. `<label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="John Smith" />`

Comment: @Orbling It's good practice to have an id on a html element :-)

Comment: @nemke: When you need to refer to it specifically, certainly.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do:

```
if ($('#main_state').html().indexOf('This field is required')==-1){
    $('#main_state').append('<label class="check error" generated="true">This field is required.</label>');
}
```

Check the html in main_state for the occurrence of `'This field is required'` - if it can't be found `-1` then add it as normal.

Comment: I guess this method will not be quite fast.

Comment: Honestly, I think in this case, every solution that access the DOM in the loop to check whether element is added, adds unnecessary overhead. A simple flag is probably sufficient here.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('label.check[generated=true]').length === 0) {
   //do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my comment: It seems that it does not depend on any loop variable so why don't you put the line before the loop?

---

If you cannot do that, the trivial solution would be to set a flag:

```
var added = false;

for(...) {
    if(!added) {
        // add the thing
        added = true;
    }
}
```

Granted, it is not that fancy and if you run the code that contains a loop a second time, the label will be added again. But from your description it seems you always want to add the label when you run the loop. This solution at least avoids querying the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Make a small jquery plugin like:

```
$.fn.appendif = function (selector, content) {
  if ($(this).children(selector).length > 0) return this;
  $(this).append(content);
  return this;
}
```

And use one of the following:

```
$('#main_state').appendif('.check.error', '<label class="check error" generated="true">This field is required.</label>');

$('#main_state').appendif('label', '<label class="check error" generated="true">This field is required.</label>');

$('#main_state').appendif('label[generated="true"]', '<label class="check error" generated="true">This field is required.</label>');
```

I think this would be the easiest way.

**UPD:** I mean this is the easiest way if you do it in a jquery-style loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( 0 ==  $('label[id=error_field]', $('#main_state') ).length )
{
    $('#main_state').append('<label id="error_field" class="check error" generated="true">This field is required.</label>');
}
```

I wrote this out of the back of my head, but it should work, or atleast give you the idea.

with:

```
$('label[id=error_field]', $('#main_state') ).length
```

jquery checks if the element already exixts within `$('#main_state')` element